# Fold burst of many emails into one?

Tags: email, postfix, filter

We are running an SGE job scheduling system. Users can let SGE send out emails in case of jobs being cancelled. In the case of a user having large array jobs (say 100'000k entries) and killing all of them at once (quite easy with `qkill -u USER`), the user's mail account will be swamped with emails.

All email appears to be sent from `root@qmaster.example.com` and have the subject `"Job <numeric job id> (<name of script>) Killed"`.

All email is run through a postfix instance that is configured to be a mail proxy in that it collects jobs from all nodes and then forwards them to the actual mail host of the organization.

I would like to achieve the following:

- Hold back all email for, say, 30 seconds until forwarding.
- Consider the emails of the last 30 seconds and check whether there are any duplicates (same `To:`, subjects only differ in the numeric job id).
- If more than, say, 10 such similar emails were received then:

  - Create a "folding" email with subject "Folded emails for many jobs () Killed"
  - Show body of first 5 emails
  - Then display `"And <number> similar emails were dropped"`
  - Set email time to current time and put into queue.
- In the case of this happening multiple times, the `<number>` above should be incremented accordingly.
- Emails older than 30 second should then be sent.

I guess I did not find the correct keywords but I could not find the right place to hook in such a script. What would be a good location for such a script?

I don't have a problem with writing such a script, but if anyone knows of something existing, I would be interested to learn about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in the end I solved this by writing a [mail filter/milter](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html) that works as follows:

- If the message fits a `From:`/`Subject:` pattern, it is further processed. Otherwise, it is directly accepted.
- In the case of processing, put it in a sqlite database with a timestamp and a `To:` field.
- If there are `==` X messages in the last Y seconds, send out a warning message that tells the recipient that their email was filtered/dropped.
- If there are `<` X messages in the last Y seconds then relay email.
- If there are `>` X messages in the last Y seconds then drop email.

When using transactions correctly, it can be guaranteed that (1) no more than X emails are sent out in Y seconds and that (2) a warning message "that future emails will be dropped" can be sent on reaching the threshold exactly once.

So far, this works nicely.

Note that this could also be expanded to merging the emails into one summary after the burst is over but in the end I was not willing to invest the time in implementating this.